openapi-typescript-codegen Pagination in React from Spring Boot
I have a React TypeScript app with Spring Boot.
In my Spring Boot BE I have implemented Pagination and the endpoint looks like this:
ResponseEntity<Page<TransactionResponse>> getTransactionsByDateAndCategory(Pageable page);

Then in my React app I have generated the service using the 'openapi-typescript-codegen' package.
/**
 * Get transactions filtered by date and category
 * @param page
 * @returns PageTransactionResponse Get transactions based on the date and category
 * @throws ApiError
 */
public static getTransactionsByDateAndCategory(
    page: Pageable
): CancelablePromise<PageTransactionResponse> {
    return __request(OpenAPI, {
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/api/v1/transaction/getTransactionsByDateAndCategory',
        query: {
            'page': page,
        },
    });
}

Now, If I do a request, then the URL looks like
.../transaction/getTransactionsByDateAndCategory?page%5Bpage%5D=0&page%5Bsize%5D=10

This is totally wrong and not understandable by the BE.
Do you have idea why does the 'openapi-typescript-codegen' generates the service like this and how to solve withouth changing the service manually?
thanks in advice
